# Prevent MaterializeCSS modal close if data was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, materialize

How can I do this with MaterializeCSS?

If a user changed something in the modal and is trying to close it (by clicking outside, <kbd>Esc</kbd> button, or close button on modal), I want to confirm that action.

The `complete` option of the modal constructor only runs after the modal is closed.

This is how I catch the user changing the modal data:

```
var form_changed = false;

$('.modal').find('input, textarea, checkbox').on('change', function() {
    form_changed = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't seem possible out-of-the-box.

After peeking at the [source code](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/e959765ca3f32630217ffc4c295488ce595c6e39/js/modal.js), I came up with this:

```
function addCloseHandler($modal, handler) {
    var modal = $modal[0].M_Modal;
    modal._close = modal.close;
    modal.close = function () { handler(function () { modal._close(); }); };
}
```

Usage:

```
// $('.modal').modal();

addCloseHandler($('.modal'), function (close) {
    form_changed ? confirm('Confirm?') && close() : close();
});
```

Comment: Can't assign `$modal[0].M_Modal` to `modal` (`modal` value after is `undefined`)

Comment: You need to initialize your modal with `$('.modal').modal();` before that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm added modal initialization before handler - no `undefined` now. But still not working (no confirmation window after closing modal), so I'm added debug command to `addCloseHandler` (simple `console.log('[!] Breakpoint');`). And it's not shown in Chrome console when I close modal window.

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using Stack Snippets or jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ta01oy19/ Works. I had this `$('#...').modal({complete: ...});` block after `addCloseHandler()`. Now fixed. Thanks!